# Streaming iMac's Audio to iPad

Tags: ipad, audio, imac, streaming

I want to stream all audio output from my iMac to iPad. By the way, I know, there are only app which named [Airfoil](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) for that functionality. But I'm searching inexpensive alternatives.

So do you know any alternative application or method for this topic?

Answer (score 1):

You could compile this yourself: https://github.com/trenskow/AirFloat

Comment: I tried it. But I don't want to stream with iTunes only. I want to stream whole audio output from iMac to iPad. Just like Airfoil.

Comment: Did you try clicking with ⌥ on the volume icon in the menu bar? It should show all audio devices including all airplay devices.