# Output Macbook audio to iPhone or iPad

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, ipad, mac, audio

This question is a duplicate, I know.

Duplicate: [Send audio output of MacBook to iPhone for remote listening](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34730/send-audio-output-of-macbook-to-iphone-for-remote-listening)

However the age of this question and answer is about 5 years. Mac OS and iOS updates change and so do software.

The question is again, how could I output my audio from my mac to my iPhone or iPad? The App Airfoil was suggested in the the question above however I'm sure there are better or newer alternatives.

I did check https://alternativeto.net/software/airfoil/ however I don't know how reliable this site is.

My preference of method would be over WiFi, or USB connection but anything is better than nothing.

**Detailed Device Specs**

iPhone 5s iOS 10.3.3

iPad 3rd Generation iOS 9.3.5

**NOTE:** as suggested from [Streaming iMac's Audio to iPad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218117/streaming-imacs-audio-to-ipad), this open source alternative was available however it hasn't been updated. https://github.com/trenskow/AirFloat (requires iOS 9.2.1 and self-compiled with Xcode from a Mac)

Macbook Pro Retina (Model 10,1) Mid-2012. macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Even if a suggestion doesn't fit the older models above, they are welcome for others that this may help!

Thank you Ask Different community!

Comment: I would also love an updated answer. I added a bounty to the question, to hopefully get some attention.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wouldn't be so sure there are better alternatives. AirFoil is still updated regularly, and as its a rather rare need to stream *from* a computer to an iDevice (and not an AppleTV, HomePod, Miracast, Chromecast, Bluetooth speakers), it's a safe a reliable bet. You could also take a look at the AirSquirrels programs, (Reflector, AirParrot, etc.), but I'm not sure they actually do what you want precisely.

Comment: Yes! I’ve been using Airfoil happily for six years now, with no complaints. It’s regularly updated and works like a charm. @jahhein if you aren’t satisfied with the answer from the previous question, can you explain *why*?

Comment: The major downside to Airfoil is a significant lag, usually about 2 seconds. It doesn't matter for just listening to music, but the audio from Skype or Netflix will be completely out of sync with the video.

Comment: Airfoil is only avaiable for Music & Sound, not Video because of the sync problem.